# Is there a word for what one feels when they have a shift in perception/change of view because of exposure to opposing ideas?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, a pious person who, out of curiosity or due diligence, reads a variety of secular work or attends events of that nature, which, even slightly, makes that person doubt their faith (or at least make them less sure of their previously strongly-held beliefs)?

Another is when a staunch capitalist is exposed to leftist economic theories and begins to understand their points and considers them, whereas before they would've hand-waved them away immediately.

In short, a word to describe that "I was blind but now I see" feeling (but not totally converted to the other side)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108137/discussion-on-question-by-nicheese-is-there-a-word-for-what-one-feels-when-they).

Comment: It seems that the first example is regarding the doubt itself, whereas the second is about the new belief. Is the latter what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> I was blind but now I'm **enlightened**

**enlightened** (adj.)

> Having greater knowledge, understanding, or insight; (in later use)
> esp. having or showing a rational, modern, and well-informed outlook;
> free from prejudice or superstition.
> OED online

> **1** Freed from ignorance and misinformation
>
> *An **enlightened** people*
> *An **enlightened** time*
>
> **2** Based on full comprehension of the problems involved
>
> *Issued an **enlightened** ruling*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enlightened)

> Showing understanding, acting in a positive way, and not following
> old-fashioned or false beliefs:
>
> *The school has an **enlightened** policy of teaching boys to cook.*
> *These days she's much more **enlightened** in
> her views on education.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/enlightened)

---

> I assessed my situation: having been misdiagnosed with Parkinson's
> disease by a neurologist and gone through a horrific brain surgery to
> control my tremors that left me with dysphasia (trouble speaking) and
> muscle weakness—and didn't completely stop the tremors anyway—I became
> **enlightened** when I read books such as *Medication Madness* by Peter Breggin, MD. He explains what happens to the brain when a person
> is put on psychotropic drugs to control anxiety and depression:
> [Susan
> Gordon; *The Benzo Monster*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5IOPCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&dq=%22enlightened%20when%20I%20read%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitgeq-7diDAxUeEFkFHSzOBGkQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22enlightened%20when%20I%20read%22&f=false) (2020)

> The Chief Interpreter during the Kihae year (1839), Yu Chin-gil argued
> that Catholicism was an orthodoxy by confession that, **enlightened**
> after reading a few pages of the *Ch'ǒnju silu*, he visited one believer
> and borrowed from him the books and then immediately converted to
> Catholicism.
> [Jai-Keun Choi; *The Origin of the Roman Catholic Church
> in Korea*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sydu4aOL-WoC&pg=PA320&dq=%22enlightened%20after%20reading%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh3b358diDAxUfFFkFHVW_D8w4FBDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22enlightened%20after%20reading%22&f=false) (2006)

Answer (score 0):

If this is of concern, I think saying the person "had an epiphany" is a more respectful and neutral way of expressing this than saying they were enlightened -- enlightenment implies that they were in the dark for holding the belief they had previously held, a belief that could still be held by a number of other people.

When someone has a complete change in what they think or believe, in their position on an issue, etc., it's not always going from wrong to right, or from ignorant to educated.  And if I were a fervent believer in what the person turned away from when they changed their mind, I would not appreciate the implication that my belief was wrong or ignorant.

The third definition of "epiphany" in the AHD is "A sudden insight or intuitive understanding," which describes what you are talking about.